# Como puedo hacer que un h2 se adapte al contenido de un input

Tags: javascript, css

estoy desarrollando un simulador de decisiones empresariales y tengo un problema:
Hay apartados en el cual los chicos tienen un input para ingresar un valor y luego de este hay un h2 con posición absoluta que indica si es dinero, unidades, porcentaje, etc
El problema es que necesito que este h2 se adapte al largo de el valor del input, para que no se no se posiciones por delante de este...
Probe hacer algo con javascript y funciono, con un event listener input, detecta cuando el valor cambia, le calcula el lenght al value del input y segun este le agrega padding-left
El problema es que mientras mas caracteres agrego en el value, este h2 se aleja demasiado el final del input.
a idea es que el h2 que dice "UN." no se desplace tanto a la derecha cuanto mas caracteres sean ingresados.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const unidades = document.getElementById('unidades');

let padding = `padding-left: ${input.value.length * 90}px`;
unidades.setAttribute('style', padding)

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let padding = `padding-left: ${input.value.length * 100}px`;

  unidades.setAttribute('style', padding)
  // Esta función se ejecutará cada vez que se ingrese un nuevo carácter

});
```

```css
.col-100 {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

.col-100 form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-100 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-weight: 300;
}

.page-title {
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  font-size: 80px !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 100%;
}

h2#unidades {
  bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.box-pagination a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-pagination a.active {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-100">
  <form action="controllers/update_decisiones.php" method="POST">
    <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap page-title">
        <h2>PRODUCCION</h2>
        <h6>ORDEN DE PRODUCCION</h6>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-wrap">
      <div class="d-flex position-relative justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <input id="input" name="produccion" type="number" value="0" size="auto">
        <h2 id="unidades" class="position-absolute">UN.</h2>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">Produccion para el periodo actual</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="active" href="?page=01"></a>
      <a href="?page=02"></a>
      <a href="?page=03"></a>
      <a href="?page=04"></a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Tengo una propuesta un poco diferente a tu idea original, pero que podría servirte.

Lo que yo haría, es fijar la posición de "UN." (Lo cambié de `h2` a `span`) y hacer que el texto del input se ingrese a la derecha, utilizando `class="text-end"`, para que al escribir el texto se vaya recorriendo al a izquierda.

**Nota:** Tal vez la posición del texto no es perfecta a como la necesitas pero es un ejemplo demostrar el funcionamiento de `class="text-end"`.

Ejemplo:

```css
.col-100 {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

.col-100 form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-100 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-weight: 300;
}

.page-title {
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  font-size: 80px !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 50%;
}

#unidades {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.box-pagination a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-pagination a.active {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-100">
  <form action="controllers/update_decisiones.php" method="POST">
    <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap page-title">
        <h2>PRODUCCION</h2>
        <h6>ORDEN DE PRODUCCION</h6>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-wrap">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <input id="input" name="produccion" type="number" value="0" class="text-end">
        <span id="unidades">UN.</span>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">Produccion para el periodo actual</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="active" href="?page=01"></a>
      <a href="?page=02"></a>
      <a href="?page=03"></a>
      <a href="?page=04"></a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu ccolaboracion!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!